# C#, Winform: How to pass information from one form to another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two forms, Form1 and Form2.
Form1 is already open in the background and form2 is open above in `showdialog()`.
I would like to call a method in Form1 from Form2 before closing it.
Here is my code:

```
// In the form1
form1  frm = (form1)Form.ActiveForm;
frm.AfterConnect();
Close();
```

Comment: This question has been answered many times now. Please, make a use of the search function.

Comment: pass the reference of the Form1 to Form2 on starting?

Comment: Does `Form1` create and show `Form2`?  If so, you can require an instance of `Form1` in the constructor for `Form2` and pass a reference when creating it.

Comment: I have not found a suitable answer to my problem m.rogalski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the form and call the method, e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

Application.OpenForms
  .OfType<Form1>()     // Among the all opened forms of Form1 type 
  .LastOrDefault()     // Take the last one (or null if there's no such form)
 ?.AfterConnect();     // And call AfterConnect() on it (if the form has been found)
```

Comment: If instead of calling the method found in Fom1, I would like to access a method in a Usercontrols ... How?

Comment: If understand you right, you want to fire control's event (e.g. click a button - `MyButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {...}`); if it's your case I suggest *extracting a method*, exposing it as a public one: `public void DoSomething() {...}` and call in the event handler: `MyButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {DoSomething();}`. You still can call this exposed method with the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a property (of type Form1) in Form2. Then when opening Form2 from Form1 set the property. Now you can call any public methods in Form1 from Form2.